# How can I cut a custom height wooden door threshold? Table saw & planer

Tags: table-saw, door, planning

I have a piece of 2x8 redwood, and need to make a threshold for the following inswing door configuration:

[image: door threshold]

The door is exterior inswing with no overhang at all (Mediterranean style home).

I have access to a large table saw, planer, hand planer, routing table, hand router, bandsaw and other woodworking tools.

I'm a capable novice.  What sequence of cuts would you suggest? I'm considering two profiles, optimized for shedding water:

[image]

I've prototyped one, but the undercut at the concrete edge was hard, and I never figured out a reliable sequence of cuts to ensure the top of the threshold remained flat:

[image]

Comment: You comfortable doing the notch/coutout for the underside on the table saw? If so this is simple — starting with a piece that's longer than you need, route the groove for the drip edge first, saw the notch for the underside while the piece is still rectangular, mark for the slope on the ends and then run the hand planer along the top until you meet your lines. Cut to final length and you're done. Should take all of ten minutes, including any final sanding.

Comment: The largest available table saw blade is not quite deep enough to make the underside cut.

Comment: Okay then do the deepest cut possible for the long cut (the surface that will eventually be horizontal) then do the shallow cut at 90° to this and finish the cut using a hand saw? The inside corner might not be that neat (can be cleaned up by sanding or with a chisel obviously) but you could probably leave it without it being a big deal, and nobody will see it after installation.